# Border bottom just beneath the text

Tags: css

I have a div block i want to apply border-bottom just beneath the text and not throughout the whole div block
the div block is

```css
#info-header {
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    margin:100px 10px 10px 10px;
    font-family: Poiret One;
    color:lightyellow;
    border-bottom: 1px solid whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<div id="info-header">
  find us through 
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML code as well.

Comment: Why don't you use text-decoration:underline css

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your text in an inline element like `<span>` and apply border to it.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="info-header">
  <span>some text here...</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#info-header span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid whitesmoke;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

***Note***: You can make your element `inline-block` if you wants to apply block level properties but keep it behaving like an inline element. This way you can also control the `border-width` and the distance between text and border line.

```css
body {
  background: green;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
#info-header {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin:100px 10px 10px 10px;
  font-family: Poiret One;
  color:lightyellow;
}

#info-header span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid whitesmoke;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="info-header">
  <span>some text here...</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add css property text-decoration: underline

Answer (score 0):

You should use text-decoration property.
In your case its: 
`text-decoration: underline;`
You can also use text-decoration for overline and line-through read about [CSS text-decoration Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-decoration.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `display` value for an another `block` level.

```css
html {
  background: lightgray
}
#info-header {
  font-size: 40px;
  /*text-align: center;
    margin:100px 10px 10px 10px;*/
  display: table;/* shrinks on content */
  margin: 10px auto;/* margin:auto instead text-align for this block  */
  font-family: Poiret One;
  color: lightyellow;
  border-bottom: 1px solid whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<div id="info-header">
  find us through
</div>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZBNgNN)

Answer (score 0):

Give the `<div>` a **fixed width** and give it a {margin: 0 auto} *for centering*

```css
body {
  background: #131418;
  text-align: center;
}
#info-header {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  color: lightyellow;
  border-bottom: 1px solid whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<div id="info-header">this is a nice title</div>
```